# What would be an iswgraph() substitute when coding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to determin via JavaScript which Unicode code points
of a JavaScript string are printable or not. Accessing the
code points itself via codePointAt() works.

In C/C++ I would then use with a Unicode locale:

> The iswgraph() is a built-in function in C/C++ which checks
> if the given wide character has an graphical representation or not.
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iswgraph-in-c-c-with-examples/

What would be a JavaScript substitute, method or function, that
can be called from within a browser or node.js and that delivers
a similar indication?

Answer (score -1):

Unlike unicode_utils.py, we can compress the Unicode data and reduce to 1% of the 1114111 entries. Unicode CONTROL, FORMAT, and others can be used. The [Dogelog runtime](https://www.dogelog.ch/) currently gives.

The meaning is:

General Category = 15 = Cc (CONTROL)

The encoding of General Category is from Java, not from .NET.
[image]

The two built-ins and the unicode data are realized via JavaScript. How this slim Unicode code point classifier was rolled is documented here. It also contains the source of the compressor:

**Preview: Unicode general categories Prolog API. (Jekejeke)**
https://gist.github.com/jburse/03c9b3cec528288d5c29c3d8bbb986c2#gistcomment-3808667

**Preview: Unicode numeric values Prolog API. (Jekejeke)**
https://gist.github.com/jburse/03c9b3cec528288d5c29c3d8bbb986c2#gistcomment-3809517